# Is there a way of adding 2 dimmensional array to 2 dimmensional array list in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I know how to add a one dimmensional array to a one  dimmensional array list 
i.e

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>  
 (Arrays.asList(array));
```

However,I'm not sure what needs to be done  to add a two dimmensional array to a two dimmensional array list .Below posted is the code.

```
 int[][] myPoints = {{2,3},{4,5},{7,8},{9,10}};

 ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>
 (Arrays.asList(myPoints));????
```

Comment: What do you mean by `add`? Do you want to initialize new ArrayList with content of two dimensional array? How should its content look like? Should your list be one dimensional? Or maybe you want to create List of Lists containing integers?

Comment: Two dimensional arrays are internally implemented as an array of an arrays.  Similarly, you'll likely **not** want an `ArrayList<Integer>` but rather something more akin to an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve one-dimensional arrays from int[][] it's basically:

```
ArrayList<int[]> arrOfArr = new ArrayList<int[]>();
int[][] myPoints = {{2,3},{4,5},{7,8},{9,10}};

arrOfArr.addAll(Arrays.asList(myPoints)); // here's the one-liner doing the job
```

And if you want to flatten your 2D array to list of integers there's no other way than do it manually by iterating over every element of your array. Which, I suppose, you can.

Answer (score 0):

If Java 8 is an option for you, you could use the [Stream API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to accomplish what you want in *one* line:

```
int[][] myPoints = {{2,3},{4,5},{7,8},{9,10}};
List<List<Integer>> myPointsAsList = 
    Stream.of(myPoints).map(point -> Arrays.asList(point))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```